# I cant get bytecode and abi

Tags: solidity, blockchain, smart-contract

I am completely noob to solidity . I am following a tutorial for solidity . Here I have a file name compile.js . When I run this ,I am supposed to get bytecode and abi of my contract . But I got some error saying "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" How to solve this .

here is my compile.js file :

```
const path= require('path');
const fs= require('fs');

const solc=require('solc');

const inboxPath=path.resolve(__dirname,'Contracts','inbox.sol');

const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf-8');

module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).Contracts[':inbox'];
//console.log(solc.compile(source,1));
```

after ruuning this file on terminal I got tons of values but at the end I got this error saying

> > RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I am completely a newbie ,I dont want to give up . I tried some solutions ,it seems not to work .

here is my contract :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract inboxx {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory intialmsg) {
        message = intialmsg;
    }

    function setmessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

Comment: what command did you run in terminal?

Comment: node compile.js

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to solidity please use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) , there you can easily get the bytecode and abi , https://medium.com/@ultrasoundchad/an-introduction-to-solidity-and-remix-91b710865934